# Routing error "No route matches" in non-resourceful route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a route set up that I think should work but instead gives me the following routing error:

```
No route matches {
  :action=>"show", :controller=>"orders", 
  :id=>#<Order id: nil, 
    user_id: nil, 
    paid: nil, 
    created_at: nil, 
    updated_at: nil, 
    trip_id: nil
  >
}
```

I am using Rails version 3.2.13.

In `routes.rb` I have `get 'orders/new/:trip_id' => 'orders#new', :as => :new_order`. This comes before `resources :orders` in `routes.rb`.

In the view, I have `<%= link_to 'Click here to register for this trip.', new_order_path(@trip.id) %>`. This produces the following (what-seems-to-be-correct) HTML in a case where `@trip.id = 1`: `<a href="/orders/new/1">Click here to register for this trip.</a>`.

When I run `rake:routes`, this line (seemingly correctly) is among those that are generated: `new_order GET    /orders/new/:trip_id(.:format)                      orders#new`.

Other order-related rouates from `rake:routes` are
`orders GET    /orders(.:format)                                   orders#index
                                   POST   /orders(.:format)                                   orders#create
                                   GET    /orders/new(.:format)                               orders#new
                        edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)                          orders#edit
                             order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                               orders#show
                                   PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                               orders#update
                                   DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)                               orders#destroy`

In `orders_controller.rb`, the following line appears as the first line in my new method: `@trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])`.

In the console when I try `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/orders/new/1"` I get `=> {:controller=>"orders", :action=>"new", :trip_id=>"1"}`, which seems to be right. So frustrating.

What I can't figure out is why when I click on the link, I get the routing error shown above in the first paragraph. **Of interest, when I comment out `resources :orders` in `routes.rb`, the intended action (i.e., `OrdersController.new`) is dispatched**... but then, of course, I lose the resourceful routing that I use elsewhere. Please help!

Comment: Show full views and controller code, please.

Comment: @ Зелёный, the HTML seems to get generated as expected, so it's not clear to me how showing the full view code would help. Regarding the controller code, do you want to see the entire controller or just the new (and possibly show) method? Thanks.

Comment: I request the full code because, the error show us `:action=>"show", :id=>#<Order id: nil>`, you claim about `new_order_path` it's not clear, so please show me a full view and a full related controller, if you want a help, otherwise i can't help you.

Comment: Please include code in the question, not in comment, formatted it as in your editor.

Comment: For some reason the `new` route you're looking for is getting conflated with the `show` route. Could you paste all lines related to orders in `routes.rb` and the result when you do `rake routes`?

Comment: @radhika, please see above. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's getting messed up with the default rails `new` path. It would be worth naming it something else. Also if you don't need the default `new` path that rails applies you can change `resources :orders` to `resources :orders, only: [:show]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I ended up solving this problem myself and feel a bit stupid about not seeing it earlier. I forgot that I had introduced a new layout used by the view in question. This layout included `link_to order_path(@order) if @order`. This was the line that was, in fact, causing the error. `@order` existed, but it had not yet been persisted, so `@order.id` did not exist; this prevented it from matching the resourceful show route for `@order`: `order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                               orders#show` and causing the error. **I fixed the problem by changing `link_to order_path(@order) if @order` to `link_to order_path(@order) if @order.id`.**

Answer (score 0):

You can not add routes like that

```
get 'orders/new/:trip_id' => 'orders#new', :as => :new_order
```

Rails will understand this as a show path 
Instead add like this

```
get 'orders/:trip_id/new/' => 'orders#new', :as => :new_order
```

Comment: I initially had it as `get 'orders/:trip_id/new/' => 'orders#new', :as => :new_order`--and I just tried it again--but I get the exact same error.

Comment: What is it producing in html for link

Comment: The HTML being produced for the link (as listed above) is `<a href="/orders/new/1">Click here to register for this trip.</a>`.

Comment: There is the error ,I think you have not restarted the server,If it is producing the same error,then add the url manually /orders/1/new

Comment: restarting the server does not fix it (it's apparently not necessary in development mode to restart the server after changes to routes.rb).

Comment: Did you try adding the url something like `<%= link_to 'Click here to register for this trip.',' /orders/#{@trip.id}/new' %>`

Comment: I don't see why I should have to. The URL in the HTML seems to be getting generated perfectly already. It's the routing that happens after clicking on the link that's generating the error.